# Context API ComponentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I have a context.js file where state is defined.

```js
errorsFormEmployee: {
    firstName: true,
    lastName: true,
    email: false,
    phone: false,
    accountNumber: true,
    rate: false,
},
```

After leaving the Route I would like to use componentWillUnmount to change the value into state context

```js
errorsFormEmployee: {
    firstName: false,
    lastName: false,
    email: false,
    phone: false,
    accountNumber: false,
    rate: false,
},
```

This is my Route:

```js
import { AppContext } from '../../context';
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';

class AddEmployee extends Component {
    state = {
        isMount: true,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ isMount: !prevState.isMount }));
        // console.log(`Zamontowano ${this.state.isMount}`);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ isMount: !prevState.isMount }));
        // console.log(`Wymontowano ${this.state.isMount}`);
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.context);
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                {context => {
                    return (
                        <div className="addEmployee">
                            <h1 className="page-title">Dodaj pracownika</h1>
                            <ValidationErrorMessage />
                            <AddEmployeePageForm />
                            <div />
                            <Prompt
                                when={context.checkEmptyFields(this.state.isMount)}
                                message="Czy napewno chcesz porzucić wprowadzone dane?"
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}

export default AddEmployee;
```

component is activated when any value from the state key is "true". After leaving Route I would like the values to return to the initial value. In this moment after exiting Route the error message is still visible

AppProvider I have in my Root file

```js
render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <AppProvider>
                    <div className="app">
                        <Navigation />
                        <Footer />
                        <div className="content">
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path="/" exact component={InstructionPage} />
                                <Route path="/add-employee-page" component={AddEmployeePage} />
                                <Route path="/employees" component={EmployeesPage} />
                                <Route
                                    path="/employeePanel/:name"
                                    render={props => <EmployeePanelPage {...props} />}
                                />
                                <Route path="/ranking" component={RankingPage} />
                                <Route component={ErrorPage} />
                            </Switch>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </AppProvider>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Show as where you have `AppContext.Provider`. 

Soooo. 
Pass a callback function to the provider. for example `changeState(state)`. 
Get `changeState` from Provider into `AddEmployee`. On Unmount do `changeState(this.state)` - this will update your context.

Comment: I added in description